# What is the range of gl_FragCoord

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

What is the range of `gl_FragCoord.xy` ? I know `gl_FragCoord`s are screen coordinates but what is the actual range? `( 0, width - 1 )` or `( 1, width )`? And what kind of error (if any) would glsl compiler generate say I did something like `gl_FragCoord.x - 5` when i do some fragcoord based calculation?

ps: I don't need normalization.

Comment: Why would you think that the compiler would generate an error if you subtracted one number from another?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant using them as array indices :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gl_FragCoord coordinates are indexed starting from 0.

The expression `gl_FragCoord.x - 5` would result in a value in the range [-5, (width - 5) - 1]

Comment: Not quite. By default GL uses pixel center sampling, so add 0.5. See other answer.

Answer (score 18):

I did a test to the actual range of `gl_FragCoord.xy`, by using the following shader code and `glReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 1024, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, xxx)` to get the output of the shader from my framebuffer object, and the FBO had attached a texture which's internal format is `GL_R32F`.

```
out highp vec4 Output;

void main()
{
    Output = vec4(gl_FragCoord.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The actual result is: `gl_FragCoord.xy` is in the range [0.5, 1023.5], not [0.0, 1023.0].

Comment: From the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf): "*By default, gl_FragCoord assumes a lower-left origin for window coordinates and assumes pixel centers are located at half-pixel coordinates. For example, the (x, y) location (0.5, 0.5) is returned for the lower-left-most pixel in a window*" Pay attention to **pixel centers** concept.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_coordinate_origin
There are two layout qualifiers that can affect the result. origin_upper_left and pixel_center_integer. pixel_center_integer will be shifted by a half-pixel, so that the center of each pixel is an integer value.

Comment: thankx, i use `vec4 coord=gl_FragCoord-0.5;
        int index = int(coord.y * width + coord.x);`